# ASP.NET Core - Is there any way to put the viewbag on javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I tried to put viewbag data to javascript in order to fill the table without refreshing the whole page when modifying any data. And it is not working, but on html it's working .

Here's my code..

```
fillDatatable();

function fillDatatable() {
    $('#TableRecords').html(
    @if (Context.Session.GetString("cart") != null)
    {
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.cart)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.Items.ItemID
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Items.ItemModelDescription
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
            <input id="@("UnitPrice" + item.Items.ItemID)" class="form-control text-right b-r-xl" value="@item.Items.ItemUnitPrice" oninput="return change_unitprice('@item.Items.ItemID')" />
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
            <input id="@("Quantity" + item.Items.ItemID)" class="form-control text-right b-r-xl" value="@item.Quantity" oninput="return change_quantity('@item.Items.ItemID')" />
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
            <label id="@("Subtotal" + item.Items.ItemID)">
                @(item.Quantity * item.Items.ItemUnitPrice)
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-rounded" asp-controller="purchaseorderheader" asp-action="Remove" asp-route-id="@item.Items.ItemID"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>
        </td>
     </tr>
     }
     }
     );
}
```

Where do am I wrong? Is there any way to make it right? any recommendation for better way is very much accepted. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the ViewBag data in js like this:

```
var obj = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.cart));
```

Besides, you can not write the c# code in the js function. If you don't want to refresh the whole page, you can use ajax to request backend to get the updated data, then replace the data in orignal table with the returned data.

**Update:**

```
var purchaseOrderList = new List<trnPurchaseOrderLists>
{
    new trnPurchaseOrderLists
    {
        PurchaseOrderID = "1",
        Quantity = 10,
        Items = new mfItems
        { 
            ItemID = "1", 
            ItemModelDescription= "A"
        }
    },
    new trnPurchaseOrderLists
    {
        PurchaseOrderID = "2",
        Quantity = 11,
        Items = new mfItems
        {
            ItemID = "2", 
            ItemModelDescription= "B"
        }
    },
};

ViewBag.purchaseOrder = purchaseOrderList;
```

JS

```
var obj = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.purchaseOrder));
console.log(obj);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I already did this sir but it's undefined. Im still looking for solution.

Comment: @JeffreyEstrera can you show the data in ViewBag.cart.

Comment: function fillDatatable() {
            var PurchaseOrder = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.purchaseOrder));
            if (PurchaseOrder != "") {
                var tableHTML = "";
                $.each(PurchaseOrder, function (index, value) {
                    tableHTML += "<tr><td>" + value.Quantity + "</td></tr>";
                });
                $("#TableRecords").html(tableHTML);
            }
        }

I think it's because of the object. because there's another object inside the object.

Comment: public class trnPurchaseOrderLists
    {
        public mfItems Items { get; set; }

        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }

        public decimal UnitCost { get; set; }

        public string PurchaseOrderID { get; set; }
    }


public class mfItems
    {
        [Key]
        public string ItemID { get; set; }

        public string ItemModelDescription { get; set; }

        public decimal ItemUnitPrice { get; set; }
    }


those two is what im trying to retrieve

Comment: Hi @JeffreyEstrera , see my update, I can get the value. Also, if you want to get he `quantity` value, the first letter needs to be lowercase   `value.quantity`.

Answer (score 0):

could be your js is running before the document has uploaded? try putting your function into document.onload or window.onload (not sure which it's been a while since I've worked with js and web apps)

Comment: Yes it's running before the document has uploaded and it's still not working. I'm searching about my problem here but its seems I couldn't find any similar to mine.